# Update text on a website live from an external XML

Tags: javascript, html, ajax, xml

I'm a back-end programmer tasked with creating a front-end element on a site.

I have to take only two data points from an external XML file and have then both placed within the site's existing html, and have it update every few minutes.

The xml tree is large and has several parent elements, I only need two child elements from the first parent element "Main-Library"

Here is what the xml looks like. I compressed it so only the first child of the first two parents are shown:

```
<Root>
    <Main-Library>
            <Book>
                <Title>Book Name</Title>
                <Author>John Smith</Author>
                <Genre>Fiction</Genre>
                <Loaned>2020-09-03 13:13:48</Loaned>
                <Price>-13.30</Price>
            </Book>
            .
            .
            .
    </Main-Library>
    <Second-Library>
            <Book>
                <Title>Book Name</Title>
                <Author>John Smith</Author>
                <Genre>Fiction</Genre>
                <Loaned>2020-09-03 13:13:48</Loaned>
                <Price>-13.30</Price>
            </Book>
            .
            .
            .
    </Second-Library>
</Root>
```

I need to take Loaned and Price from the first parent element Main-Library and place them within the following html:

```
<p class="feed">
<span class="feed-text-large">Status: </span>
<span class="price">$35.98</span>
<span class="timestamp">Loaned at 13:13 on September 03, 2020</span>
</p>
```

with price and the date coming from the XML, and refreshing as the xml changes.

Any help to get me started on this will be greatly appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: Assuming the structure of the XML never changes, you _could_ try using an XSLT file with a small amount of JavaScript to refresh the page every now and again.

Comment: "refreshing as the xml changes" is going to be a challenge; you're going to have to poll the file and see if it's changed. Using ETags will help mitigate that, but that's a whole topic in itself....

Comment: I've reopened this because the question cited as a duplicate does not include the requirement for periodic refreshing, which I think is key to choosing the right approach.

Comment: @MichaelKay Reopening a question using your gold badge for a question you have an answer on is pushing the limits of propriety... Not to mention pushing your company's product while doing so.

Comment: I'm afraid I take no notice of badges and such like, I didn't know it needed any particular privileges. I just felt that closing it was a mistake, because there was a key aspect to the question that wasn't present in the cited duplicate. As for it being my product, I answer questions with the solution that I would use if I had the problem, whether that's my product or not, in the hope that the OP will find it informative.

Answer (score 0):

First of all - is it possible to use JSON? If yes, go for it and show how the data looks in JSON.

Steps to do:

1. Create a function that will retrieve data

```
function getData() {
  return fetch(theUrl).then(response => response.text())
}
```

2. Create a function that will parse the data

```
function parseData(str) {
  const data = (new window.DOMParser()).parseFromString(str, 'text/xml')
  // never did anything with XML so this might be wrong
  // that's why JSON would be A LOT EASIER
  // this should get the first Book
  const Book = data.querySelector('Root Main-Library Book')
  const price = Book.querySelector('Price').innerHTML
  const loaned = Book.querySelector('Loaned').innerHTML
  return { price, loaned }
}
```

3. Print the data

```
function printData(data) {
  const priceTarget = document.querySelector('.price')
  const loanedTarget = document.querySelector('.timestamp')
  priceTarget.innerHTML = data.price
  loanedTarget = data.loaned
}
```

4. Create a function that will be run periodically

```
function update() {
  getData().then(parseData).then(printData)
}
```

5. Run the function once and set an interval

```
const minutes = 5
update()
setInterval(update, minutes * 60 * 1000) // interval in ms, so 60*1000 gets us a minute
```

I'm not 100% sure if it will work - my main concern is `parseData()` because I've never done anything with XML in JavaScript.

EDIT: That code will read data from first Book element. If you want to list all Books, the code will have to be different. Let me know, I'll answer you in about 8 hours if no one will be quicker than me. Goodnight

Answer (score -1):

With Saxon-JS you could do this by running an XSLT 3.0 stylesheet along the following lines:

```
<xsl:template name="display">
  <xsl:result-document href="#timestamp">
    <xsl:text>Loaned at {/Root/Main-Library/Book/Loaned
                         => translate(' ', 'T')
                         => xs:dateTime()
                         => format-date('[H00].[m00] on [MNn] [D1o], [Y0001]')
                        }</xsl:text>
  </xsl:result-document>
  <xsl:result-document href="#price">
    <xsl:text>${/Root/Main-Library/Book/Price}</xsl:text>
  </xsl:result-document> 
  <ixsl:schedule-action wait="60000">
    <xsl:call-template name="refresh"/>
  </ixsl:schedule-action>
</xsl-template>

<xsl:template name="refresh">
  <ixsl:schedule-action http-request="....">
    <xsl:call-template name="display"/>
  </ixsl:schedule-action>
</xsl-template>
```

This is just a sketch to illustrate the idea if you want to go down this route. The main benefit (I know it appeals to some more than others) is that there's no Javascript to get wrong.

Disclaimer: Saxon-JS is my company's product.